# Giving a superclass access to enum types that have not been defined yet

Tags: c++, enums, derived-class, base-class

So I have a base class `A` that has these functions:

```
virtual void DoSomething(SomeNameSpace1::EnumID ID) = 0;
virtual void DoSomething(SomeNameSpace2::EnumID ID) = 0;
virtual void DoSomething(SomeNameSpace3::EnumID ID) = 0;
```

I also have 2 derived classes `B` and `C` that define how these functions work. The way `SomeNameSpace1::EnumID`, `SomeNameSpace2::EnumID` and `SomeNameSpace3::EnumID` are defined depends on whether or not it is used in class `B` or class `C`. Thus, I have two files:

enum_defn_B.hpp:

```
namespace SomeNameSpace1 {

enum EnumID  {

    ENUM_TYPE_1 = 0 ,
    ENUM_TYPE_2
}

namespace SomeNameSpace2 {

enum EnumID  {

    ENUM_TYPE_3 = 0 ,
    ENUM_TYPE_4
}

namespace SomeNameSpace3 {

enum EnumID  {

    ENUM_TYPE_5 = 0 ,
    ENUM_TYPE_6
}
```

enum_defn_C.hpp:

```
namespace SomeNameSpace1 {

enum EnumID  {

    ENUM_TYPE_7 = 0 ,
    ENUM_TYPE_8
}

namespace SomeNameSpace2 {

enum EnumID  {

    ENUM_TYPE_9 = 0 ,
    ENUM_TYPE_10
}

namespace SomeNameSpace3 {

enum EnumID  {

    ENUM_TYPE_11 = 0 ,
    ENUM_TYPE_12
}
```

The problem I have now is that the base class `A` does not recognize the type `SomeNameSpace1::EnumID`, `SomeNameSpace2::EnumID` or `SomeNameSpace3::EnumID`. It also would not make sense to include either the `enum_defn_b.hpp` or the `enum_defn_c.hpp` files because they are specific to the two derived classes. What can I do in this case? I read some stuff about forward declarations but wasn't sure if that would be the correct method.

In the derived classes I would include each of their `.hpp` `enum_defn` files but what about the base class?

Comment: Your design is flawed - a virtual function cannot be overridden by a function with a different signature. If the base function takes one enum and a derived function uses another enum, overriding will not take place.

Comment: You broke the [ODR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule) (One Definition Rule).

Comment: I agree with eran and Jarod42. From my understaning you are looking for a common base interface for different kind of service, what about using functors? http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/functors-function-objects-in-c++.html, e.g. remove y9our enumerations with a hierachy of class. An hint to fix the poor design.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to use polymorphic behavior caused by different values?
Isn't a switch-case more appropriate? It could be done also with templates, but those are a [pretty advanced topics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modern_C%2B%2B_Design).

Anyway, may-be this explanation will give you some insights:

1) If you want to use a type, it should be declared prior to usage.

2) The derived classes have to include the declaration of the base class, and implicitly the definition of the enums.

3) If each derived class file would define its enums with already existing names in a different way, it would harm one [definition rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule) - one of the basic concepts of C++.

Answer (score 0):

A should make sense irrespective of whether or not any Bs or Cs are derived from it. What should A think of SomeNameSpaceX other than that it doesn't seem to exist?